# How to delete DOM element based on attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML code from Sharepoint and I was wondering if it's possible to delete this specific DOM element based only on the "text" attribute?

```
<ie:menuitem menugroupid="200" text="new docs view" onmenuclick="window.location = '/some link/';" type="option" id="zz36_View1"></ie:menuitem>
```

Using Firebug I can simply right click the above line and click delete element. How do I do this using Javascript w/ Jquery?

Here's some context of where the above line came from:

```
<span style="display:none">
    <menu compactmode="true" id="zz34_ViewSelectorMenu" type="ServerMenu">
        <ie:menuitem menugroupid="100" text="All Documents" onmenuclick="window.location = '/some link/';" type="option" id="zz35_DefaultView"></ie:menuitem>
        <ie:menuitem menugroupid="200" text="new docs view" onmenuclick="window.location = '/some link/';" type="option" id="zz36_View1"></ie:menuitem>
        <ie:menuitem menugroupid="300" text="Explorer View" onmenuclick="window.location = '/some link/';" type="option" id="zz37_View2"></ie:menuitem>
    </menu>
</span>
```

I tried something like:

```
<script language="Javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>

<script language="Javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('ie:menuitem[text*="new docs view"]').remove();
    });
</script>
```

but it doesn't really work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$('ie\\:menuitem[text*="new docs view"]').remove();
//or
$('menuitem[text*="new docs view"]').remove();
```

Just a guess since I really don't know how well jQuery works with namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ie:menuitem[text*="new docs view"]')
```

ie:menuitem is not a standard HTML element. Therefore jQuery is likely interpreting `:menuitem` as a [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). That's likely the root of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`$('ie\\:menuitem[text*="new docs view"]').remove()` may work.

Answer (score 0):

That's how you can do. Assuming your `menu` is the first children: (dirty way)

```
$("span").children(1).children().each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("text") == "new docs view"){
        $(this).remove();
        return;
    }
});
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/naveed_ahmad/wdTwL/

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the `:` in your selector:

```
$("ie\\:menuitem[type='option'][text='All Documents']").remove();
```

Shown working here: http://jsfiddle.net/Codemonkey/tduVq/1/